# Inserting rows into kickstart sortable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-kickstart

How can i insert many rows into kickstart sortable table? I install `<tr>...</tr>` code with jQuery method `appendTo` to tbody of table (like that: `$("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>".format(a, b, c)).appendTo("#items-tbody");`), then I can't sort any column. I have errors like:

`TypeError: i is undefined - kickstart.js (line 288)`
  in firefox, or

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined`
 in chrome.

I know that kickstart adds own additional attributes, but how can I add them after the page loads?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Without it it's hard to help you.

Comment: @dfsq, it's not easy to create fiddle with 3side code( This code from kickstarter js file add needed attributes as well: ```$('table.sortable').each(function () {
            $(this).find('thead th').each(function (index) {
                $(this).attr('rel', index);
            });
            $(this).find('th,td').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('value', $(this).text());
            });
        });```.  Perhaps it would be more convenient to do at updating table DOM (with MutationObserver or smtn).

Answer (score 0):

Your exact error is caused by not setting the **value** attribute for the inserted 's.   Kickstart uses TinySort for sorting, which apparently uses the **value** attr.

ie:

```
var tbody = $(SELECTOR_FOR_TBODY);
tbody.append("<tr id='ROW_FOR_NEW_DATA'/>");
var tr = $("#ROW_FOR_NEW_DATA");`
tr.append("<td value='MyNewValueForTD1'>MyValueForTD1</td>");
tr.append("<td value='MyNewValueForTD2'>MyValueForTD2</td>");
```

In order to preserve proper formatting of striped rows (and possibly some other behaviours), you must also do something like this after adding all new rows:

```
$('table').find('tr:even').addClass('alt');
$('table').find('tr:first-child').addClass('first');
$('table').find('tr:last-child').addClass('last');
```